# BeautifulSoup - How do iterate through entire html page to add a class to every <td>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautifulsoup to make changes to table elements.  More specifically, I am adding a class to the tbody and the td elements.  This works great, but only for the first matching element.  I can't figure out how to iterate through the rest of the matching elements on the page.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(combine_html, "html.parser")
soup.find('tbody')['class'] = 'list'
soup.find('td')['class'] = 'fuzzy'
soup
```

The following changes happen

```
<tbody> changes to <tbody class="list"> 
The first <td> changes to <td class="fuzzy">
```

~~~Update~~~

I'm not getting any input, so maybe I don't have my question posted with the correct tags, or the answer is stupid simple, so no one is posted.

I was able to get this working - but it is really ugly.  See code below:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
# import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString

# Select columns from csv file
csv_columns = ['Email', 'Recipient Name', 'Department', 'Clicked Link?']

# Set input csv file to read from nd specify columns using csv_columns variable
df = pd.read_csv('camp1_beneficiary_fullcsv.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=csv_columns)

# Set the HTML header
# Set Bootstrap CSS
# Set CSS location for list.min.js Javascript - mainly the list class
# Set div id for list.min.js
html_header="""
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="def.css">
<div id="users">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="em">
    Sort by name
  </button>
"""
# Set HTML 'footer'
# Specify list.min.js external javascript file and code

html_footer ="""
<script src="list.min.js"></script>
<script>
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'fuzzy' ]
};
var userList = new List('users', options);
</script>

"""

# Generate HTML body using df.to_html from Pandas
html_body = df.to_html(classes=["table-bordered", "table-striped", "table-hover"])

# Combine html header, body, and footer into variable
combine_html = (html_header + html_body + html_footer)

# Find elements in HTML and add classes to support javascript classes for filtering

soup = BeautifulSoup(combine_html, "html.parser")
soup.find('tbody')['class'] = 'list'
soup

f = open('test.html','w')
f.write(str(soup))
f.close()

f = open('test.html', 'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

newdata = filedata.replace("<td>", "<td class='fuzzy'>")

f = open('final.html', 'w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find_all` function. [Here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) is the documentation.

```
for td in soup.find_all('td'):
    td['class'] = "list"
```